# not able to insert record in firebase table using Angular 6

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

not able to insert record in firebase table using Angular 6, I am using real-time database

Component code below:-

```
*CreateRecord() {
   let jsonob: jsonob = {
  'MSG-21A7605D-A48E-4291-ABDA-4DFE046FE597': {
    msg_text: 'Test Person1'
  }
};
this.crudService.create_NewStudent(jsonob).then(resp => {
        this.msg_text = "";
        console.log(resp);
     }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
     });
 }
 create_NewStudent(record) {
   return this.firestore.collection('messages').add(record);
 }
```

Firebase Rules is below:-

```
{
  "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
   }
}
```

messages table is below:-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/InWGE.png
Error Message: 
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
   at new FirestoreError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:93048:28)

Comment: It's my first experience at the firebase, what will be insert query for real-time database, please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question says "I am using real-time database", but the code is using Firestore.  On top of that, you're showing rules for Realtime Database, which in no way affect access to Firestore.  The error message "Missing or insufficient permissions" is suggesting that your Firestore security rules (not your Realtime Database rules) are disallowing access.

Basically, you're going to have to go back and make sure you're using the correct database system across the board.

Comment: It's my first experience at the firebase, what will be insert query for real-time database, please guide me. –